# How to check if a String is in valid format or not in Java8

Tags: string, java-8

I want to validate if a given String is in below format or not.

String validString = "Emp_idIn645745,48576845,8347683,8734682";

some of the invalid Strings are below:

- "EmpIdIn46374,49587,498576"
- "Emp_Id=736437"

Will it be possible to achieve this in java 8?

Comment: You cannot just show one example and say "this is the format", that is not how specifications work. When actually writing down what the format is you will probably end up with a suitable regex basically automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If so, then it's not a problem with Java 8. But it depends on what exact rules this string should contain. You will definitely have to build your own validator function.

I would start by checking the first part with `<your-string>.startsWith("Emp_idIn")`.
For the numbers, you have to find your own way to validate them using your rules.